# Установка matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, python-3.10

Пытаюсь установить в `spider` `matplotlib`, Windows, через командную строку выполнил установку:

```sh
pip install matplotlib
```

все установилось корректно, но в IDL этот модуль не видно, видит только `matplotlib_inline`, так же установил NumPy, SciPy, Matplotlib, IPython, Jupyter, Pandas, SymPy, Nose. Изначально был голый интерпретатор python3.10.

Comment: у вас несколько питонов. в одни вы ставите модули, а ожидаете их работы в другом.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы действительно решили пользоваться Spyder, matplotlib, numpy, scipy,  jupyter pandas sympy .... а теперь уперлись в то, что у вас что-то где-то не работает -  то совет один -  кончайте заниматься садомазохизмом, удаляйте все напрочь, и устанавливайте с нуля Anaconda ([www.anaconda.com](http://www.anaconda.com)) -  там точно есть все что вам нужно, точно в рабочем состоянии и точно последние на сегодняшний день работоспособные версии. И все что вам потребуется в первые три-четыре года ознакомления с экосистемой Python.